# Gaps in data series for Wijmo's wijlinechart

Tags: charts, wijmo

So I am using a Wijmo 2.1.6 wijlinechart to display multiple data series, each of which may or may not have discontinuities--i.e., places where the line should break. I have been able to get these to display by breaking the series apart on their discontinuities--see below for an example of two series with multiple such discontinuities.

The problem is that this means that wijmo treats each piece of the original series is now its own series, so instead of all the pieces that belong to the same ur-series having the same color, they each have different colors.

My question is whether there's someway I can force these pieces to all be displayed in the same color, so that it looks like a single series with gaps.

I'm guessing this probably means finding a way to force wijmo to display a given series in a specific color. The other option is that it might have something to do with the [hole](http://wijmo.com/wiki/index.php/Linechart#hole) attribute, but I've not been able to find much information about that at all, and my experiments using it and display: "excludeHole" have not been encouraging.

[image]

Comment: [link]http://wijmo.com/wiki/index.php/Version_2.1.7 appears to suggest that there was an issue with line holes that was fixed in version 2.1.7; can anyone confirm whether this may be the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the problem was with the version of Wijmo I was using. Upgrading to 2.3.6 allowed me to fix the problem by using a sentinel value to mark the gaps rather than splitting the series, and then constructing the charts like so.

```
            var HOLE = 4294967295;
            //...
            $("#first_chart").wijlinechart(
            {
                hole: HOLE,
                display: 'excludeHole',
            //    ... other options...
            }
```

Unfortunately, null does not appear to work as a sentinel value, at least in 2.3.6; it has to be a number. I wound up using max int.